# Wordpress - Enable video format

Tags: wordpress, video, format

i've got a question about video´s in wordpress.

When i upload a video of .flv-format, it display´s correctly on my website.

But when i use my iPhone, the video disappear´s.

anybody could help me with this problem?

Greetings!

Comment: do you have a live website with this video?

Comment: no sorry doing it locally :/

Answer (score 0):

You say that your video is in a FLV format. If it truly is a FLV (a format originated by Macromedia to be streamed to the Flash Player), then that's not supported by iOS devices (or most mobile devices, for that matter).

You should probably use MP4 files with H.264 video, at least for mobile delivery.